# How to reuse .csx files

Tags: azure-functions

In this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp), it's discussed how one .csx file can call another. The following example is used:

The code in this .csx file loads the "..\shared\order.csx" files to use the Order class.

```
#load "..\shared\order.csx"

using System;

public static void Run(Order myQueueItem, out Order outputQueueItem,TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed order...");
    log.Info(myQueueItem.ToString());

    outputQueueItem = myQueueItem;
}
```

This is the order.csx code:

```
public class Order
{
    public string orderId {get; set; }
    public string custName {get; set;}
    public string custAddress {get; set;}
    public string custEmail {get; set;}
    public string cartId {get; set; }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return "\n{\n\torderId : " + orderId +
                  "\n\tcustName : " + custName +             
                  "\n\tcustAddress : " + custAddress +             
                  "\n\tcustEmail : " + custEmail +             
                  "\n\tcartId : " + cartId + "\n}";             
    }
}
```

What's not clear to me is how the order.csx got saved in a folder named 'shared' and how the 'shared' folder got created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can't add such folder directly from Azure Functions user interface, so you'd have to use one of the other methods of deploying files to App Service (and thus Functions).

E.g. you can go to Kudu (click your app -> `Platform features` -> `Advanced tools (Kudu)`, then go to `Debug console` -> `CMD` -> `site` -> `wwwroot` and add your folder there.

You can also use FTP, Git, VSTS and other available deployment methods.

On a side node, I would suggest you having a look at precompiled C# functions, where the problem of referencing proper files is solved at compile time. That's the way Microsoft recommends these days.